# Is there a way to controll an Android Device via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, esp32

I'm making a 3D-printed bluetooth ESP32 controller.
I'd like to manage my music with simple actions (play/pause, volume up/down, previous/next).

Is it possible to access an android device's functions only using bluetooth ? (Without coding a "receiver" app on my phone)

Ideally, I'd like to send a bluetooth request from the ESP32 that would trigger the right function

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like you want to build a remote control for your Bluetooth audio device.

Check the Bluetooth specification for the [AVRCP profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Audio.2FVideo_Remote_Control_Profile_.28AVRCP.29) (Audio Video Remote Control Profile). Android supports AVRCP 1.3 since version 4.3 (API level 18).

Comment: Yeah, the Bluetooth audio device being and android phone. I'd like to access the basics media functions I cited above just like a bluetooth pair of headphones or speaker would.

Thanks for the link, i'll check right away !